# The right adjective for "fry"

Tags: word-request

What is the correct adjective to describe when something is fried for too long or at a high heat?  To fry "strong"? To fry "hard"? Can't pick the word that would sound authentic.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific word for it, but you could say that something is burnt, black or overcooked, though I would interpret the last as boiled for too long rather than fried for too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are participles allowed? If so, an adverb plus the participle are idiomatic: for example, **over fried** or **badly fried** or **excessively fried**. In many contexts, **charred**, **over cooked**, or **burnt** would also work.